# How to write A React component library that allow scss variables to be overwriten

Tags: reactjs, sass, rollup, rollupjs

I have few react projects which have few component they share.
So I wanted to create a library that contains the components they share.

For example I have a `ActionButton` component which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import './ActionButton.scss';

const ActionButton = ({ children }) => (
    <button className="action-button"> {children}</button>
 )

export default ActionButton;
```

This is the scss file:

```
@import "../../styles/variables";

.action-button {
    background-color: $primary; // this is defined in the variables scss file.
}
```

and in `variable.scss`

```
$primary: blue !default;
```

Now I want to be able to create a library with that `ActionButton` with the ability to change the value of `$primary`.

Im using `rollup` to build the library with this configuration:

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import scssVariable from 'rollup-plugin-sass-variables'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import url from 'rollup-plugin-url'
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup'
import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
    input: 'src/index.js',
    treeshake: false,
    output: [
    {
       file: pkg.main,
       format: 'cjs',
       sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
   plugins: [
     external(),
     postcss({
       modules: false,
       extract: true
     }),
     url(),
     svgr(),
     babel({
        exclude: 'node_modules/**',
        plugins: [ 'external-helpers' ]
     }),
     resolve({
       extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
     }),
     commonjs(),
     scssVariable(),
   ]
}
```

Now in the project that uses this library I tried to import the `variables.scss` and overwrite the variable but it does not work:

```
// this is in the package that uses this library
@import '<PackageName>/src/styles/variables.scss;
$primary: red;
```

Then when I draw the `ActionButton` it is still blue.

What do I need to do in my library to allow this kind of functionality?

Comment: In what file you are using `@import '<PackageName>/src/styles/variables.scss;`?

Comment: in the main scss file of the project who is using the library I'm trying to create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import `!default` variables into your particular project before the component's variables.

This is the description from SASS docs:

> Variable Defaults: !default
>   You can assign to variables if they aren't already assigned by adding the `!default` flag to the end of the value. This means that if the variable has already been assigned to, it won't be re-assigned, but if it doesn't have a value yet, it will be given one.

It converts to logic, then if the default variable value was already defined in the project it would not be redefined by the next default value.
Only first `!default` variable value applies.

Example:

```
$primary: blueviolet !default;
$primary: greenyellow !default;

.element {
  color: $primary; // will resolve to 'blueviolet'
}
```

Check on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sfbwtj?file=style.scss

UPDATE:
To use it with your current config, please import styles directly with scss files from your library:

```
// this is in the package that uses this library
@import './your-redefined-variables.scss';
@import '<PackageName>/src/styles/variables.scss';
@import '<PackageName>/src/styles/library-styles.scss';

.element {
  color: $primary;
}
```

Comment: This will not work since the library is after build, meaning there are not longer variables when I look on the output css of the lib the value of the variable is already displayed as a color and not variable

Comment: Why didn't you mention in initial question what you are using CSS files instead of SCSS when import from your library?
Since you compiled styles to CSS  no sense to import variables.
You have to import scss files from your library.

Look at Bootstrap library for example. It provides default style with precompiled CSS (like you do now) and a possibility to extend styles with variables if you import their SCSS files to overwrite default values.

Added example to answer.

Comment: Just to be clear to make it work you need to extract all the `scss` imports from every component to a single `scss` file and then import it in the project like you did with `library-styles.scss`

Comment: The SCSS variables should be automatically injected into each of the components, in library, so the adoption layer will not have to import it, since it's supposed to be "transparent" to the adoption layer